# Failed to import mrjob on EMR

Tags: python, python-import, emr, mrjob

So i'm trying to run my mrjob but getting the error on the first line:

```
ImportError: No module named mrjob.job
```

I'm launching job as the following:

```
python main.py --bootstrap-mrjob -v -r emr --emr-job-flow-id j-XXXXXXXXX ../data/data.txt
```

I also tried to add the following line into my mrjobs.conf:

```
bootstrap:
- sudo pip install mrjob
```

It doesn't work.
So how to fix it?

EDIT:
Actually i don't get this error if i'm creating the cluster from command line, but if i'm tring to run script on the already running cluster it fails with this error.

EDIT:
so the one more difference is that on cluster created from command line i have the following step

```
  PENDING (cluster is BOOTSTRAPPING: Running bootstrap actions)
```

but on already running cluster i don't have it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in mrjobs.conf explicitly: `-c mrjobs.conf`

Comment: I did, it doesn't help

Comment: I saw your edits, if the cluster is already running then you don't have to bootstrap mrjob, as it was already bootstrapped when the cluster was created.